# How to get CPU usages for several JBOSS nodes in LINUX

Tags: java, linux, jboss

Is there a way to get the CPU usages of several jboss nodes in linx?

I stared the nodes according to the following syntax

> home/xxx/jboss-4.0.3SP1/bin/run.sh -c node1 -b localhost
>
> home/xxx/jboss-4.0.3SP1/bin/run.sh -c node2 -b localhost

But the problem is the process name is "java" for both of the processes above.(But have difference PID s)
Is there a way to differentiate above two process ?

If I use top | grep 'java' It showing all but not individually.
E.g: I want to get the CPU usage of node1 only , node2 only , both node1 and node2.
I play with some grep parameter changes but no luck.

And also I don't need to watch like "top" command I want the CPU usage of that java process (e.g: node1) at that time.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `ps` command instead of `top`:

```
ps -C java -o pid,tid,pcpu,cmd
```

For more details on `ps`, see [`ps(1)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps)

If you want to filter the results, the popular tool is `grep`:

```
ps -C java -o pid,tid,pcpu,cmd | grep 'home/xxx/jboss-4.0.3SP1/bin/run.sh'
```

Comment: Both process names are "java" how can I differentiate them that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks. But there are lots of out put even a single PID. And also can't differentiate when there are two java processes.

Comment: Ok, threads omitted.  You should be able to distinguish different processes by their `pid` and possibly their arguments.

Comment: Then I have to get the PID before run this command. Then It's a problem.As I mentioned in the question i need get the CPU usage of node1. But I don't know the PID for that. (other than pidof java)

Comment: No, this should include the distinctive `-c node1` text that you said you're looking for.  Try it out and read the manpage for the details.

Comment: It's the one in the answer.  Right up there ^^

Comment: I tried ps -C java -o pid,tid,pcpu,cmd but the problem is all the java processes coming for that but i need only the node1 or node2. And also other java processes also coming for this command. (other than the jboss java processes (node1,node2 etc . . . ))

Comment: wow. Great thanks. from ps -C java -o pid,tid,pcpu,cmd | grep 'node' I can get all the nodes and from ps -C java -o pid,tid,pcpu,cmd | grep 'node1' I can get nide1